# Questions on threads (thread.wait())

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a question

Let's say that we have one thread running (thread1) that "runs" a second (thread2) via executorService. If I pause thread1 by "thread.wait", will thread2 still be running?

Thank you

Comment: Why not test it? Also what do you think will happen? Why do you think so?

Comment: Because I have a problem in the computer  use right now nad I cannot install Java. I think it will not wait.

Comment: There are online compilers like https://ideone.com/.

Comment: Great one,thank you.

Answer (score 0):

waiting on one thread does not stop/block other threads. So you can wait on thread 1 while thread2 (or thread 3, or any other from the Executor Service's threadpool) will continue running.

Answer (score -1):

If thread1 was able to start thread2 before the wait() method was executed, then yes, thread2 will continue running. However if thread1 wasn't able to start thread2 by that time, none will run.